# DateTime + TZ -> NodaTime conversion

Tags: c#, nodatime

When I look about how to convert time to NodaTime, I find many posts but not a single straight answer about what I need.

I have:

```
- A DateTime object (DateTime myDateTime)
- An Olson timezone (var TZ = "America/Los_Angeles")
```

I want:

```
- A ZonedDateTime object (ZonedDateTime myZonedDateTime)
```

Ideally, I'm looking for some helper like:

```
var myZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.From(myDateTime, TZ);
```

but all the samples I see go through turning the date into a string and then parsing the string, which seems quite odd.

There is a ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset() method, but the offset and the TimeZone are different things since the TZ can handle daylight savings.

Comment: What is the "kind" of the `DateTime`, and what do you want to happen if the `DateTime` value is either ambiguous or skipped? (I'd expect this to be a matter of using `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(myDateTime).InZoneLeniently(zone)` or similar.)

Comment: Those are airplane flight times; they are expressed in local times along with an Olson timezone; the time is in local for display purpose and internally we need to turn them to UTC (factoring daylight savings) for some calculations.

Comment: I have not given thoughts yet about the ambiguous vs. skipped part since this is a very new problem I am facing and I am trying to figure things out :)

Comment: That's what they *logically* are - but what would `myDateTime.Kind` return? Where does `myDateTime` come from to start with? (If it's a string, it would be best to parse it straight to a `LocalDateTime`.) I assume you've found `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[id]` to get the `DateTimeZone`?

Comment: the dates comes as strings with an Olson TZ; and yes, I have managed to get the timezone.

Comment: Okay, if they come as strings, you could do the whole thing in one pass using a `ZonedDateTimePattern`. I've added an answer based on the information in the question, but if you want to update it with a string version, I could write an additional part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(myDateTime);
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[id];
var zoned = local.InZoneLeniently(zone);
```

Except:

- You may well want to write your own rules instead of using `InZoneLeniently`
- You may want to use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(id)` if you're not sure whether the zone ID will be recognized by Noda Time.

Comment: Since our list of time zone is rather fixes (it's airports), I'll run the whole list through NodaTime to make sure none are missing; Thanks a lot Jon, this is really helpful!

Comment: @Thomas - You may find my code [here](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/6d219c48697c550c2476) useful, which provides both TZDB and Windows time zones for all airports of the world.